# automatic regression model selection

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, regression, data-analysis

So I'm creating a mini project and I want to know is there anyway for me to compute which regression model is the best to use without testing all the models and deciding based on the metric, that is, by just seeing or going through the training data is there a way to decide which would be the best model to use in the scenario.

I am going to be writing this in python 3, so if there's any built method in scikit-learn or tensorflow for this purpose,it would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This scikit learn tool kit solves it :

https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/index.html

it is  bit computationally expensive, but you can tune it to make it faster.